# Split one big table into multiple tables based on content of acolumn in each row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I looked at previous similar questions and only found one answer with the following code splitting the data into 2 tables:

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name        TABLE SPLITTER
// @namespace   http://www.w3schools.com/
// @description DESCRIPTION!!!
// @include     http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://raw.github.com/tomgrohl/jQuery-plugins/master/jcookie/script/jquery.jcookie.min.js
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==
$(function(){
        // YOUR JAVASCRIPT CODE HERE
        // YOU HAVE JQUERY INCLUDED
    setTimeout(function(){
        var mainTable = $("table");
        var splitBy = 3;
        var rows = mainTable.find ( "tr" ).slice( splitBy );
        var secondTable = $("<table id='secondTable' style='background:pink;'><tbody></tbody></table>").insertAfter("table");
        secondTable.find("tbody").append(rows);
        console.log(secondTable);
        mainTable.find ( "tr" ).slice( splitBy ).remove();

    }, 3000);
});
```

I am looking for something like this that will split the information to tables base on the amount of different options i have.

ultimately i would like something like:
[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCZkd.png)

Or even better remove the type from the output and have it show before each of the new tables like this: [option 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSm0s.png)

Not sure if that even possible and would love some help.

Comment: I would recommend [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the optimal solution, you can get the idea and improve it.

Read JS comments.

```js
var dynamicData = $('#dynamicData'); // To identify the parent that we will append data to.

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.types').each(function(){ // loop on each type and check if that type not appended inside '#dynamicData' as 'h5', if no,t append it and append a table related to it
    var name = $.trim($(this).text());
    var check = $('h5#i_' + name , dynamicData).length;
    if (check === 0){
      $(dynamicData).append('<h5 id="i_' + name + '">' + name + '</h5>');      
      $(dynamicData).append('<table id="t_' + name + '" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered"></table>');
      $('table#t_' + name).append('<thead>'+
        '<tr>'+
        '<th>Product</th>'+
        '<th>Price</th>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '</thead>'+
        '<tbody>'+
      '</tbody>');
    }
  });
  
  $('#allContent > tr').each(function(){ // loop on each row in '#allContent' and read '.types' class, then clone this row and remove the type then append it inside the target table using id
    var name = $.trim($('.types',this).text());
    $(this).clone().find('.types').remove().end().appendTo('table#t_' + name + ' > tbody');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<h4 class="text-center text-danger">Before:</h4>
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>  
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="allContent">
    <tr>
      <td>TV</td>
      <td>250$</td>
      <td class="types">Product</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Channel</td>
      <td>1$</td>
      <td class="types">Service</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Channel</td>
      <td>1$</td>
      <td class="types">Service</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DVD</td>
      <td>14$</td>
      <td class="types">Product</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Support</td>
      <td>15$</td>
      <td class="types">Team</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h4 class="text-center text-danger">After:</h4>
<div id="dynamicData"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try adjusting it to work, my table and html is created by an automated system so the table lack id and labels. that why i used         var mainTable = $("table");
        var splitBy = 3;

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is make a unique list of the types. Then loop over that list, cloning the original table for each. Then loop through the cloned table and remove everything that you don't want there. Definitely not the most efficient, but it's simple and it works.

```js
let types = [... new Set($('table.original tr td:last-of-type')
              .get().map(type => type.textContent))];

//create a container for the cloned tables
$('table.original').after(`<h4>After:</h4><div class="cloned-tables"></div>`)

//loop over types, clone tables, modify accordingly
$.each(types, function(index, type) {
  $(`<p class="type">${type}</p>${$('table.original')[0].outerHTML}`)
    .appendTo('.cloned-tables')
    .find('tr td:last-of-type').each(function() {
      if (this.textContent !== type) { this.parentElement.remove();  }        
      this.remove();
  });
});

//remove all type header cells
$(`.cloned-tables table th:last-of-type`).remove();
```

```css
h4{color: red;}
.type{color: blue;}
```

```html
<h4>Before:</h4>
<table class="original">
  <thead>  
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>TV</td>
      <td>$250</td>
      <td>Product</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Channel</td>
      <td>$1</td>
      <td>Service</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Channel</td>
      <td>$1</td>
      <td>Service</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DVD</td>
      <td>$14</td>
      <td>Product</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Support</td>
      <td>$15</td>
      <td>Team</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Another thought on using greasemonkey, make sure that the table exist and is populated before you try and do anything with it. Greasemonkey is in a different scope than the original code, so `document.ready()` is inaccurate. Sometimes things load very asychronously, which will make valid code seem broken. I tend to do something like this:

```
let loading = setInterval(function() {
  if ($('table.original').length) {
    clearInterval(loading);
    //greasmonkey code here
  }
}, 1000);
```